# How to sum the contents of a document field with symfony query builder?

Tags: symfony, document, query-builder, dql

I am just trying to get the total value of one of the fields of my documents but it's not working. What am I missing?

@ProductRepository

```
public function countTotalValue()
    {
       return $this->createQueryBuilder('a')
        ->select('SUM(a.price)')
        ->getQuery()
        ->getSingleScalarResult()
    ;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I discovered it!

```
public function countTotalValue()
    {
        $array = $this->createQueryBuilder()
            ->select('price')
            ->hydrate(false)
            ->getQuery()
            ->execute()
            ->toArray()
            ;

        $array = array_column($array, 'price');
        return (array_sum($array));

    }
```

It was returning a complex array, I had to stripe it before make the sum.